# A question on semi-stratifiable space

Tags: gn.general-topology

This question is also posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405307/a-question-on-semi-stratifiable-spaces).

A space $X$ is callled **semi-stratifiable** space if it has a $g$-function such that: for any point $x$ of $X$ and a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of $X$ if $x \in g(n,x_n)$, then $x_n \to x$.

Note that every Moore space is semi-stratifiable. We know the cardinality of a star countable Moore space is not greater than $\mathfrak c$.

A topological space $X$ is said to be **star countable** if whenever $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is a countable subspace $K$ of $X$ such that $X = \operatorname{St}(K,\mathscr{U})$.

> **Is there a star countable semi-stratifiable space $X$ with $|X|> \mathfrak c$?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you kindly tell us what a $g$-function is?

Comment: $g: \mathbb N \times X \to \tau_X$ is a $g$-function of $X$ if for any $x$ and $n \in \mathbb N$, $x \in g(n+1,x) \subset g(n,x)$. 

Comment: It seems that you want to impose some separation axiom, since otherwise the indiscrete space (of any cardinality) would seem to be trivially semi-stratifiable and star-countable. 

Comment: It's customary in generalised metric spaces to assume at least $T_3$ ($T_1$ plus regular). This is also customary for stratifiable and semi-stratifiable spaces, AFAIK.

Comment: @Joel: maybe I should mentioned it.

Answer (score 2):

As a counterexample to this question we can consider the Katetov extension $\kappa\omega$ of the  discrete space of all finite ordinals $\omega$.

By definition, $\kappa\omega$ is the space of all ultrafilters on $\omega$ with the topology in which a neighborhood base of an ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ consists of the sets $\{\mathcal U\}\cup U$ where $U\in\mathcal U$. Here we identify $\omega$ with the set of principal ultrafilters on $\omega$. So, $\kappa\omega=\omega\cup\omega^*$ where $\omega^*$ is the set of free ultrafilters on $\omega$. The space $\kappa\omega$ is separable and hence star-countable. On the other hand, $\kappa\omega$ has cardinality $2^{\mathfrak c}>\mathfrak c$. Also the space $\kappa\omega$ is semi-stratifiable. This is witnessed by the function $g$ defined by $g(n,\mathcal U)=\{\mathcal U\}$ if the ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ is principal and $g(n,\mathcal U)=\{\mathcal U\}\cup(\omega\setminus n)$ if $\mathcal U$ is free.

Since the subspace $\omega^*$ of free ultrafilters is discrete and uncountable, the separable space $\kappa\omega$ has uncountable network weight, so is not $\omega$-monolithic. This answers question 
[Is every semi-stratifiable space $\omega$-monolithic?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267068/is-every-semi-stratifiable-space-omega-monolithic)