# Is there a star countable, semi-stratifiable space $X$ with $|X|> \mathfrak c$?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is there a star countable, semi-stratifiable space $X$ with $|X|> \mathfrak c$?

---

### Definitions

A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is called **semi-stratifiable** if there exists a function $g:\omega\times X\to\tau$ such that:

1. for any point $x$ of $X$ holds $\{x\}=\bigcap_{n\in\omega} g(n,x)$;
2. for any point $x$ of $X$ and a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of $X$, if $x \in g(n,x_n)$ for each $n$, then $x_n \to x$.

A topological space $X$ is said to be **star countable** if whenever $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is a countable subspace $K$ of $X$ such that $X = \operatorname{St}(K,\mathscr{U})$, where $\operatorname{St}(K,\mathscr{U}) = \bigcup \{ U \in \mathscr{U} : K \cap U \neq \emptyset \}$.

Comment: Is this related to your earlier question on countable tighness etc.? A semi-startifiable space obviously has countable pseudocharacter and if Lindelöf (pretty close to star countable) it would be hereditarily separable,and so countably tight. The other ound would then imply $|X| \le \mathfrak{c}$ So you need a non-separable space.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "off-topic" because it is a duplicate of this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/132209/a-question-on-semi-stratifiable-space (Technically, that's a site violation. Please don't repeat questions.)

Comment: This question (and its older duplicate) is answered in (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132209/a-question-on-semi-stratifiable-space/267286#267286). A counterexample if the Katetov extension of $\omega$.