# Is every semi-stratifiable space $\omega$-monolithic?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is every [semi-stratifiable](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Semi-stratifiable_space) space $\omega$-monolithic?

---

### Definitions

A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is called **semi-stratifiable** if there exists a function $g:\omega\times X\to\tau$ such that:

1. for any point $x$ of $X$ holds $\{x\}=\bigcap_{n\in\omega} g(n,x)$;
2. for any point $x$ of $X$ and a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of $X$, if $x \in g(n,x_n)$ for each $n$, then $x_n \to x$.

A topological space $X$ is said to be **$\omega$-monolithic** if $nw(\overline{A}) \le \omega$ for any subset $A \subset X$ with $|A| \le \omega$.

$nw(X)$ denotes the [cardinal function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_function#Cardinal_functions_in_topology)
 called [network weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#Weight_and_character), which is minimal cardinality of a network
$$nw(X)=\min\{|\mathcal N|: \mathcal N \text{ is a net for } X\}+\omega.$$

If not. What if $X$ is semi-metric space?

Note that $X$ is semi-metrisable iff $X$ is first countable and semi-stratifiable;

Comment: Could you explain what your notation $nw(\bar A)\leq\omega$ means? Also, you seem to have some grammatical issues in the rest of your question that make things confusing, at least for me.

Comment: $nw(X)$ denots the network weight of a topological space $X$.

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain what that means? For example, I don't know what the "network weight" of a space is, and I expect that many MO readers also might not know. For the benefit of those readers who do not know what this means, I think it would be better to explain.

Comment: OK, i will edit it.

Comment: Is there a motivation for this question ?It seems somewhat random..  Is there reason to think so (maybe consistently true)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a counterexample to this question we can consider the Katetov extension $\kappa\omega$ of the  discrete space of all finite ordinals $\omega$.

By definition, $\kappa\omega$ is the space of all ultrafilters on $\omega$ with the topology in which a neighborhood base of an ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ consists of the sets $\{\mathcal U\}\cup U$ where $U\in\mathcal U$. Here we identify $\omega$ with the set of principal ultrafilters on $\omega$. So, $\kappa\omega=\omega\cup\omega^*$ where $\omega^*$ is the set of free ultrafilters on $\omega$. The space $\kappa\omega$ is separable but has cardinality $2^{\mathfrak c}>\mathfrak c$. Since the subspace $\omega^*$ of free ultrafilters is discrete and uncountable, the separable space $\kappa\omega$ has uncountable network weight, so is not $\omega$-monolithic.

On the other hand, the space $\kappa\omega$ is semi-stratifiable. This is witnessed by the function $g$ defined by $g(n,\mathcal U)=\{\mathcal U\}$ if the ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ is principal and $g(n,\mathcal U)=\{\mathcal U\}\cup(\omega\setminus n)$ if $\mathcal U$ is free.

This example also answers [A question on semi-stratifiable space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132209/a-question-on-semi-stratifiable-space).